# Apache Spark GitHub code and Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Please pardon my basic question. I need to use a few classes off the latest code of Apache Spark for Spark Streaming so I can use them in my test classes e.g. [MicroBatchExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/MicroBatchExecution.scala).

However, the Maven dependencies available don't have a few classes such as the one in the link.

How do I access these?

Comment: You'd probably need to build the jars directly from GitHub source.

Comment: You can find the tarball @ https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-bin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current stable release of Spark - `2.2.1` - was released on Dec 01, 2017.

The class you referenced ([MicroBatchExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/commits/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/MicroBatchExecution.scala)) was added in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/59daf91b7cfb50b1c20eb41959921fc03103b739#diff-c2959c723f334c32806217216014362e) on Dec 14th so it is not available in the current release.

Since that class has been merged to master you can expect that it will be made available in the next stable release (`2.3.0`).

I don't think Spark publish snapshots to a publically available repo so your options are:

1. [Build the JAR](https://github.com/apache/spark#building-spark) yourself

Or

2. Wait for the current SNAPSHOT version (`2.3.0-SNAPSHOT`) to be published as an official version (`2.3.0`)

Comment: I think I should wait. Building a jar and adding that dependency is wreaking havoc on my code. Any idea by when the latest snapshot might be published?

Comment: I can't find a release schedule [here](http://spark.apache.org/) or [here](https://github.com/apache/spark) so I don't know when 2.3.0 will be released. However, the first release candidate for 2.3.0 arrived a few days ago so perhaps 2.3.0 will be released in the next few weeks.

Comment: They *do* publish nightly builds, see the corresponding section in https://spark.apache.org/developer-tools.html. Example of such snapshots: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/